# What to do with my previous jobs' 401ks? Advice for someone in his 20's

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, rollover

I'm 26 and became self-employed. I have been wondering what to do with my previous 401ks. Any help is appreciated.

Currently I have:
-$3.5k in a 401k (Ubiquity) from the company I just stopped working.
-$1k in a rollover IRA (Fidelity) from a previous job.

My plan is to not touch them until I retire, and possibly allocate 33% US stock index, 33% int stock index, and 33% US bond index.

What would be my best move to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Might also want to consider everything over to a single broker (e.g. Fidelity, Vanguard, etc) as you'll likely have many 401ks in the future and it's easier to manage them when they are consolidated.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your financial situation and risk tolerance. Are you married with kids? Do you have a mortgage or car payment? What is your overhead like?

Ordinarily, I would say that a younger person like yourself can take on a higher risk tolerance. But again, this depends on your financial situation and desired returns. Consider allocations to commodities and currencies as well. I'm not familiar with all of Fidelity's offerings, so I don't know how feasible that is. You are on the right path with your strategy, but your portfolio allocation is ultimately something for you to decide.